# Select from one table and count from another

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I would like to know how to select from one table and count from another (loop) using a single query

Table ctagories

```
------------------------------
cat_id | cat_name | parent_id 
------------------------------
1      | General   | 0
------------------------------
2      | News      | 0
------------------------------
3      | Sports    | 1
------------------------------
4     | Test       | 0
------------------------------
```

Table posts

```
--------------------------------------
post_id| title     | c_id   | active
--------------------------------------
1      | test      | 1      |  1
--------------------------------------
1      | test 1    | 2      |  0
--------------------------------------
1      | test 2    | 1      |  1
--------------------------------------
1      | Test 3    | 3      |  1
--------------------------------------
```

I want display categories `where parent_id=0` (main categories) with the post count (posts `where active = 1`) in front of it

Ex: General (2 posts)

Can anyone give me a example how to do it with a one query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    `cat_name`, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `posts` p WHERE p.active =1 AND p.c_id = c.cat_id) as post_count 
FROM `category` c
WHERE c.parent_id = 0
ORDER BY `cat_name` ASC
```

Comment: I think that `group by` with `left join` will work faster here

Answer (score 1):

try this query ,you can use subquery with select statement in query.

```
    select cat_name,
     (select count(*) 
      from post 
      where active=1 
      and c_id=cat_id
      ) as countpost 
    from ctagories 
    where parent_id=0;
```